# Strapdown gyroscopes and body frame angular velocities

Tags: kinematics, angular-velocity, gyroscopes

I am trying to make some sense on strapdown interial navigation systems, which i thought i understood...
I thought that a strapdown intertial navigation system produced **body frame expressed angular velocities** i.e. expressed on the *current local frame*.

Therefore, in order to integrate them back to find the current rotation matrix, one should first express them on the global frame, by mutliplying with the inverse of the rotational matrix, and then integrate them ( using whatever form necessary, quanternions, rotational matrices ets)
But, in many examples, i see that the angular velocities are integrated without transforming them into a global frame

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is it possible to share an example?

Comment: [Ccharacteristic example](https://github.com/GruffyPuffy/imutest/blob/master/imutest.cpp)